# how to stop npm from automatically uninstalls module upon error message

Tags: npm

I have a bizarre situation where I am installing a node module named base58-native as part of a larger package. The module has an error in it which prevents it from building. After the error, npm proceeds to uninstall and delete all of the files automatically. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

`npm install --force` will ignore any errors and keep the failed modules around.